# Wanting to add a drop down menu to reg form

Tags: taxonomy-terms, users

I want to add a drop down list to the user registration form for users to pick a category for their page to be under when signing up.

I also want it so people can click on a menu and it will take them to a page view that their catagory is under.... for example, clicking on "food" brings up a view with all pages related to food..

Is this done with the taxonomy? Or can I just set up a view to fetch the related shops from the database?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a  BLOCK-VIEW of type TAXONOMY.
2. Select the vocabulary which u have created and want to be displayed in DROP DOWN LIST.
3. In the format type,select JUMP MENU.
4. SAVE the view.
5. Assign view to a region where you want drop down menu to be displayed..

Answer (score 0):

Your first question:
The [Profile 2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module let's you add additional fields to a user profile.
If you need PHP logic have a look at [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

Your second question:
Yes taxonomy is the way to go for this and has full views integration.

Comment: to add more to the first question, you can add more fields to the user account and enable show during registration

Comment: You can also add fields to the standard user in Drupal 7. No need for Profile 2 unless you need the specific features from the Profile 2 module.

Comment: thanks heaps for the help... for each of my catagories... would the best bet be to create a view for say a category field such as "shoes" then create the view for that.?

Comment: If you're not familiar with taxonomy and views I recommend to play with it in a mickey mouse project. Also have a look at view arguments. You can add taxonomy terms as arguments to a views URL to tell the view what to show to the user.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using webform module for generating web form than there is way to add drop down list to your field by directly adding the value in options field

once you had generated your web form its there in your content region .

go to edit link part and in option field provide your drop down option in a format like

(value)|(value)

like if you want to add "x" to drop down write it in a form
eg : x|x

the content on one side of pipe is to refer the name of content in databse and other is one which is displayed on drop-down.

hope this would be helpful